# Apache2 configure pages next to reverse proxy

Tags: server, apache2, proxy

I have installed apache2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 vServer. On top of that I have configured a reverse proxy to a program which is running on port 5000. Now I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to show an other page if the program on port 5000 is not running?
2. How can I add new pages next to the reverse proxy? Like example.com/newpage. I have tried to just make a new directory 'newpage' in my document root with an index.html file. But that was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Short answers to 1. + 2.: in principle, yes; can get tricky, depending on your specific reverse proxy configuration.

One: You could use mod_proxy_balancer and configure a failover cluster consisting of two members, your local service listening on port 5000 and another VirtualHost on the same apache listening at an arbitrary port:

```
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:5000"
    BalancerMember "http://localhost:5001" status=+H
</Proxy>
```

(For this to work you would have to configure an additional VirtualHost instance on your server listening to port 5001, with a general internal RewriteRule to only response with its index page.)

Two: Without knowing your specific reverse proxy configuration, I would suggest to combine mod_rewrite with mod_proxy.

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" !^/newpage
RewriteRule ^/(.*) balancer://mycluster/$1 [P]
```

to include the above failover configuration.

**Disclaimer**

1. These suggestion are coming out of my head and might contain syntactical and logical errors; I am willing to assist if you encounter any problem with it.
2. These are just config snipplets and not running configurations.
3. Without knowledge of your apache configuration it is difficult to suggest valid solutions.